How to delete a field with a dynamic name from Firestore
I can't delete this field from firestore:

any suggestions?
I have firebaseConfig, it's just big so i didn't paste it here.
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

I tried to use code below but vsStudio's showing 'Signature declarations can only be used in TypeScript files'
updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid),{
  deleteField(fieldId)
})


What's the value of fieldId in the code you shared? Can you reproduce it with a hard-coded value instead of a variable? If so, please edit your question to show that instead.

it's the map's id that i want to delete. Here it is "hFtgZE3tjnc4gtHFBJBXcsr9YbG3drBKvDhk97V36EVhZshn0ShwMnv1"

The syntax to delete a field is:
updateDoc(referenceToDocument,{
  "fieldName": deleteField()
})

If you want to use a variable as the field name, that'd be:
updateDoc(referenceToDocument,{
  [fieldNameVariable]: deleteField()
})

